# Interior and closure on metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider $(X, d)$ a metric space, $A\subset X $, such that:

$f(A) =\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$
and
$g(A)= \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(A))$.

Show that:

1. $g(g(A))=g(A)$ OR

$cl(int(cl(int(A))))=cl(int(A))$

My idea:

$ cl (int(A)) $is a closed set. 
$ int (cl (int (A))\subset int (cl (A))$.

Since $ cl (int (cl (int (A)))) $ is the smallest closed set containing
 $ int (cl (int (A))) $ .

we have that:
 $ cl (int (cl (int (A)))) \subset cl (int (A)) $.

What about

$ cl (int (A)) \subset cl (int (cl (int (A))))$
?

2. $f (S) \cap f(S')=\emptyset$

where $S$ and $S'$  are open and disjoint sets.

anyway for part2, l come up with this idea:

Claim: Consider N=M two sets then , int(M)=int (N) and cl (N)= cl (M).
I don't have the proof for my claim as l have intuition. (Maybe l am wrong then plz correct me).

If the claim is true, then :
$S \cap S' = \emptyset $  then take int of both sides gives part2.

Please verify my claim and solution for part2 and proper answer for Part1. 
Thanks

Comment: If they are 'functions', what would you have done?

Comment: Don't know,  just wanted to learn.

Comment: $f$ is the function from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$ defined by $f(A) = \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$ for all $A\subset X$.

Comment: Thanks. Now, what is its properties? How can l show Part1?